# copas looping issue while connecting the server

Tags: websocket, lua, openwrt

I am new to lua programming and trying to implement Lua-websocket in openwrt as a client. [here is the library.](https://github.com/lipp/lua-websockets)
Was trying to use client copas library but the issue is the script is getting stopped listening server after executing once (i.e. connecting to server, receiving message, sending message). I want the script to always listen the server without any timeout or script halt.
Below is the script

```
local copas = require'copas'
local websocket = require'websocket'
local json = require('json')
local client = require 'websocket.client'.new()

local ok,err = client:connect('ws://192.168.1.250:8080')
if not ok then
   print('could not connect',err)
end

local ap_mac = { command = 'subscribe', channel = 'test' }
local ok = client:send(json.encode(ap_mac))
if ok then
   print('msg sent')
else
   print('connection closed')
end

local message,opcode = client:receive()
if message then
   print('msg',message,opcode)
else
   print('connection closed')
end

local replymessage = { command = 'message', message = 'TEST' }
local ok = client:send(json.encode(replymessage))
if ok then
   print('msg sent')
else
   print('connection closed')
end

copas.loop()
```

Here copas.loop() is not working.

On openWrt I had installed lua 5.1

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer:* you do not use Copas correctly.

*In detail:* `copas.loop` does nothing, because you have neither created a Copas server, nor a Copas thread. Check [the Copas documentation](http://keplerproject.github.io/copas/reference.html).

The `send` and `receive` actions in your script are performed **outside** Copas, because they are not within a `Copas.addthread (function () ... end)`. You also create a websocket client that is not a copas one, but a synchronous one (the default). Check [the lua-websocket documentation](https://github.com/lipp/lua-websockets) and its examples.

The solution:

```
local copas     = require'copas'
local websocket = require'websocket'
local json      = require'cjson'

local function loop (client)
  while client.state == "OPEN" do
    local message, opcode = client:receive()
    ... -- handle message
    local replymessage = { command = 'message', message = 'TEST' }
    local ok, err = client:send(json.encode(replymessage))
    ... -- check ok, err
  end
end

local function init ()
  local client = websocket.client.copas ()
  local ok,err = client:connect('ws://192.168.1.250:8080')
  ... -- check ok, err
  local ap_mac = { command = 'subscribe', channel = 'test' }
  ok, err = client:send(json.encode(ap_mac))
  ... -- check ok, err
  copas.addthread (function ()
    loop (client)
  end)
end

copas.addthread (init)
copas.loop()
```

The `init` function instantiates a `client` for Copas. It also starts the main `loop` in a Copas thread, that waits for incoming messages as long as the connection is open.

Before starting the Copas loop, do **not** forget to add a Copas thread for the `init` function.

Comment: Hey @AlbanLinard thank you for ur help. It did worked for me on openwrt also went through copas docs; I had totally messed up :P Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: When I tried this code with lua 5.3 and in the above state it was causing unclean disconnects straight away, but moving the while loop from the loop function into the init function does work, hope that helps someone this is reasonably undocumented